# UISearchController - Results show under searchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

i've been converting my searches from the old UISearchDisplayController to the new UISearchController. I've got it all working now but my last issue is with the results tableview that is shown.
The results tableview is displayed underneath the searchbar, and when you scroll down the tableview then goes through the status bar.

Attached are some images showing the issues, Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening. I've included some of the set up code from my ViewDidLoad.

[Search Tableview before searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWdKB.jpg)

[Search Tableview after searching & scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ0L9.jpg)

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[super viewDidLoad];
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

// create a filtered list that will contain products for the search results table.
self.filteredItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.listContent count]];

 // Initially display the full list.  This variable will toggle between the full and the filtered lists.
self.displayedItems = self.listContent;
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;


[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"";

// Add the UISearchBar to the top header of the table view
self.TV.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:TV.frame];
    [theView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.090 green:0.388 blue:0.643 alpha:1]];
    [TV setBackgroundView:theView];

[TV reloadData];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Search";
```

`

Thanks, 
Andrew